# json fetch in vue not working as it should

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fetch, vue-component, fetch-api

I'm building a simple test for a project of mine after watching a bunch of vue.js lessons.
My test is simple, fetch some json from an api i created with express.js and output it on the screen, I wanted do it the proper way so i build all the little components that make up my test homepage and commited the fetch through dispatching an action, this is the structure:

[image: project structure]

my submissions/action.js

```js
export default {
  async loadSubs(context) {
    

    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/api`, {
      mode: "no-cors",
    });
    console.log(res);
    const resData = await res.json();
    console.log(resData.name);
    if (!res.ok) {
      console.log(resData);
      const error = new Error(resData.message || "failed to fetch");
      throw error;
    }

    const subsList = [];

    for (const key in resData) {
      const sub = {
        name: resData[key].name,
      };
      subsList.push(sub);
    }
    context.commit("setSubs", subsList);
    
  },
};
```

my submission/mutation.js:

```js
export default {
  setSubs(state, payload) {
    state.submissions = payload;
  },
};
```

they get imported in submissions/index.js :

```js
import mutations from "./mutations.js";
import actions from "./actions.js";
import getters from "./getters.js";

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state() {
    return {
      submissions: [
        {
          name: "",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  mutations,
  actions,
  getters,
};
```

and submission/index.js gets imported in store/index.js

```js
import { createStore } from "vuex";
import SubmissionsModule from "./modules/Submissions/index.js";

const store = createStore({
  modules: {
    submissions: SubmissionsModule,
  },
});

export default store;
```

My vue components are the following(i'm leaving out the css)

- BaseCard.vue

```js
<template>
  <div class="card">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

- my Submission/SingleSubmission.vue

```js
<template>
  <div class="subList">
    <base-card>
      <h2>{{ name }}</h2>
    </base-card>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["name"],
};
</script>
```

and this is my views/Home.vue:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <single-submission></single-submission>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SingleSubmission from "../components/SingleSubmission.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    SingleSubmission,
  },

  computed: {},

  created() {
    this.loadSubmission();
  },

  methods: {
    async loadSubmission() {
      //this.isLoading = true;
      try {
        await this.$store.dispatch("submissions/loadSubs");
      } catch (error) {
        this.error = error.message || "something went wrong";
      }
      // this.isLoading = false;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

The api is just sending back a line of json, just to test if i can render something.

```js
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
const apiPrefix = "/api";

//Define the root endpoint
app.get(apiPrefix, async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.headers);

  res.json({
    name: "test",
  });
});

app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log("listening on port 3001");
});
```

RESULTS OF WHAT I'VE DONE:

this is the result of `res` object when i console log it:

[image: res object]

and this is the network tab on the browser i use:(fun fact:on Brave and Chrome the response tab is empty, while on firefox, i can see the json intended to see, but only in the developer tools reponse tab )

[image: network headers]

In the end the response status is 200 but i get nothing from the fetch expept `res` but `console.log(resData.name)` don't even gets executed and nothing is printed on the screen.

I really don't know what to do because it's seems such a stupid thing and I can't get around it.

Comment: What does `console.log(res.json());` show in `loadSubs` in `action.js` ?

Comment: @match this is the result :`ƒ json() { [native code] }`

Comment: "console.log(resData.name) don't even gets executed" - it's very unlikely that `console.log(res)` is called and `console.log(resData.name)` isn't without an error. In case there's an error, catch should be triggered, consider checking this. Otherwise both should be called. That you assign `this.error` is fragile and impractical way to debug, and you seem to not use it. Make sure it's not called, preferably with a debugger